# CRUD with JSON arrays values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, crud

I'm working to have a CRUD with a JSON file, but I have no idea how to manipulate many levels of JSON. So I have the following JSON code. What should I do, for example, if I want to add a new assistant? Is this even possible?

```
{
"events": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Noches de trova",
    "address": "Degollado #93 Centro, 28000 Colima City",
    "city": "Colima",
    "date": "Oct 10",
    "datetime": "07:00 PM",
    "price": "0",
    "description": "Noches para escuchar, sentir y pasarla bien.",
    "image": "img/banner1.jpg",
    "publisher": "Noches café",
    "assistants": [{
        "name": "Alfredo Tomas Perez Prado",
        "address": "Las brisas #356 Col. Colinas del rey",
        "age": "29"
    }],
    "activities": [{
        "name": "Registro",
        "place": "Explanada del edificio 1",
        "time": "07:00-07:30 PM"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Yes, a new assistant would be totally possible. You can use the `fs` - https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html also, basic operations on modifying JSON is totally possible. To add an assistant all you have to do is read the JSON file, parse it, do `events[0].assistants.push(newAssistant)` and then write this new JSON back to file. There are more approaches to solving this. You might want to look up stackoverflow / google for more.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for basic operations, I might look up this site or Google for more info since I'm a little bit lost with JSON. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example just load the json into a variable and you are good to go:

```js
var data = {
"events": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Noches de trova",
    "address": "Degollado #93 Centro, 28000 Colima City",
    "city": "Colima",
    "date": "Oct 10",
    "datetime": "07:00 PM",
    "price": "0",
    "description": "Noches para escuchar, sentir y pasarla bien.",
    "image": "img/banner1.jpg",
    "publisher": "Noches café",
    "assistants": [{
        "name": "Alfredo Tomas Perez Prado",
        "address": "Las brisas #356 Col. Colinas del rey",
        "age": "29"
    }],
    "activities": [{
        "name": "Registro",
        "place": "Explanada del edificio 1",
        "time": "07:00-07:30 PM"
    }]
  }]
}

data.events[0].assistants.push({name: 'John', address: '1st Street', age: 55})

console.log(data.events[0].assistants)
```

If you need to find the event by some property you would then use `filter/find` to get to it and to add the event. But otherwise is just JS object/array access.

So you can load the json, manipulate it and then export it.

Comment: Just what I was wondering. But I would have to retrieve all JSON file every time I have to modify it and then send it up to the server? What would be the best practice?

Comment: No, you should send an update to the server and have it take care of it! I.e. the 'U' in CRUD.

Comment: Well not familiar with your setup/env but sure going from server to client for crud is not the most efficient way. If there is a way to skip the transfer would be best so the CRUD is done at the server level. Again not sure what your topology/architecture it.

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON as the acronym meaning said is a valid Javascript object. You can do all valid JS operation with it.

> For Read, evaluated the text to a javascript via JSON.parse method.
>
> For Creating an array element. Use JS operation for push(), concat()
>   or even inline array addition.
>
> For Update, you could update the value of array directly as Javascript
>   allows.
>
> For Delete, you can use operation such as splice() or pop(), shift().
>   depending on what you need.

The keyword here is the JSON is a Javascript notation object. So what ever you can use in Javascript object/array can be used in JSON CRUD.